# Adding New Cython Classes or Files to Existing Project? Just doesn't work

Tags: python, c, scikit-learn, cython

I have been working on creating a new algorithm by extending sklearn's source code. Specifically I'm working on HistGradientBoostingRegressor. That's not really important. What is important is that I'm trying to add new classes to the project which are contained in .pyx files, in Cython.

For example, I want to create a new copy of the `HistogramBuilder` class, which is contained in the [`histogram.pyx` file here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/main/sklearn/ensemble/_hist_gradient_boosting/histogram.pyx). I've attempted 2 techniques which normally work in Python, but in Cython it's not working.

**Technique 1**

I simply copy and rename the class into the same file, changing the name of the class. So I created a class called `NewHistogramBuilder` into the same file. When I then try to re-compile the Cython code using `python setup.py build_ext --inplace`, I will get a whole bunch of following errors:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
                if has_interaction_cst:
                    feature_idx = allowed_features[f_idx]
                else:
                    feature_idx = f_idx

                self._compute_new_histogram_brute_single_feature(
               ^
------------------------------------------------------------

sklearn/ensemble/_hist_gradient_boosting/histogram.pyx:664:16: Python type test not allowed without gil
```

I've seen this kind of error before, when my code was attempting to do implicit type conversion when it isn't allowed, but I don't know why I would see this error since the code is exactly the same as the previous class, just with new names. It shouldn't be trying to do anything illegal.

I feel this problem comes from not correctly adding (or declaring) the new class to the project, but I can't figure out where to add (or declare) the class. There is no `.pxd` file in this folder, like I've seen in other folders.

**Technique 2**

I put my new class in a completely new file, called `new_histogram.pyx`. With this technique the files compiled fine (but maybe the compiler isn't even looking at my new file?). But then when I run the file, I get an error when trying to import the class from the new file:

```
     12 import numbers
     14 from .splitting import Splitter
---> 15 from .new_histogram import NewHistogramBuilder
     16 from .predictor import TreePredictor
     17 from .utils import sum_parallel

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.ensemble._hist_gradient_boosting.new_histogram'
```

Again, this error appears to happen because the project doesn't know that my new file even exists. How would I add this new file and class to the project correctly? I don't see anything inside the `__init__.py` file or anything?

As you all can see, I am lost regarding how to add new Cython classes and files to this project. Can someone help me?!

Thank you.